# Export plot with high quality from R to Word

Tags: r, export-to-word

I did a plot in R & I want to define some format issues in my plot but I haven't got it.

1. Is it possible define the size of plot? How?
2. I want change the font family for Times New Roman. Is it possible?
3. How do it export a plot to Word with high quality.  I tried with tiff but the plot wasn't good.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Yes. 3. Use a PNG with sufficient resolution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plots with good resolution for printing and screen display](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166931/plots-with-good-resolution-for-printing-and-screen-display) and dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395323/fonts-in-r-plots (for fonts)

Comment: i saw this links but it didn't help me. but thanks!

Comment: I only can TIFF or EPS format.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ReporteRs` package to export the plot to Word. See the following example - it will produce a *.docx* file containing an editable graph in a *vector graphics* format (high quality) with a defined size.

```
library( ggplot2 )
library( ReporteRs )
doc = docx( )

myplot = qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, data = iris
  , color = Species, size = Petal.Width, alpha = I(0.7) )

doc = addPlot( doc = doc, fun = print, x = myplot, 
  vector.graphic = T, # vector graphic instruction
  fontname = "Times New Roman",  # font specification
  width = 4, height = 4 #dim. are in inches
  )

writeDoc( doc, file = "test.docx" )
```

Comment: thanks for you help!
other question. the package ggplot2 is better than simple 'plot' of R?

Comment: library( ReporteRs ) does not exist???

Comment: yes, does not exist anymore. use officer instead