# Exporting high resolution plots

Tags: r

I need help in exporting high-quality plots from R console which can be used for academic publishing

Tried export pdf options but it is difficult to attach pdf in a word file 
Please help

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166931/plots-with-good-resolution-for-printing-and-screen-display

Comment: For inclusion in Word, try the `emf` package.( or `devemf`, I don't remember).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try exporting plots as bitmap images; e.g. as a PNG

```
png("example.png", height = 4, width = 7, units = "in", res = 300)
plot(density(rnorm(100)))
dev.off()
```

Try playing around with the parameters `height`, `width` and `res` to achieve dimensions and a resolution conform with the publishing guidelines.

Also see `?png` for more details.